# install hadoop 2.7 on ubuntu 15.04 cannot find or load main class

Tags: java, ubuntu, hadoop

I installed Hadoop 2.7.0 single node cluster on Ubuntu 15.04 following commands from [here](http://chaalpritam.blogspot.co.uk/2015/05/hadoop-270-single-node-cluster-setup-on.html) and nearly all went fine until the command formatting hdfs.

When I enter

```
$ hdfs namenode -format
```

I get error: `Could not find or load main class Djava.librarary.path=.usr.local.hadoop.lib`

In bashrc I have

```
#hadoop variables
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/lib/amd64
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"
```

In hadoop-env.sh I have

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"
```

What do I do to get rid of the error?

I'm assuming something's wrong with the java path but I can't figure what...
Can anybody help?...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the following variables alone in bashrc. Remove all other variables that you have set and then try

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
```

Let me know if still you have any problem.

Comment: I removed the variables below the four above and after running `$ hdfs namenode -format` I still get the same error saying about not finding or loading Djava.library...blahblah although I deleted the line from bashrc...

Comment: Have you ran **source ~/.bashrc** after making chnages??

Comment: yes, I did. still no change with only four variables but it worked when I added the ones you suggested should be removed. I must have missed this command when running formatting command before. thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it looks like you are getting java error. You need to configure JAVA_HOME properly. JAVA_HOME on .bashrc and hadoop-env.sh should be same.

```
$java -version
```

what is the location of your bin/java and bin/javac?

Comment: The path for both is /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle but if I put this path both into .bashrc and hadoop-env.sh I get the same error.

Comment: are you able to format namenode properly.  also check the double quote in export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The problem was that I was setting the `JAVA_HOME` env variable in the `hadoop-env.sh` file.

I believe the '.' separated path appears when you set the `JAVA_HOME` variable using the following command

```
set JAVA_HOME=/my/path/to/java
```

Instead of this you should simply have

```
JAVA_HOME=/my/path/to/java
```

And everything will start up correctly.